# OpenCV face recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

Im am trying to use opencv to perform face recognition on a static image by comparing it against a database of images and printing the prediction to a txt file, this is the code i have put together but I'm receiving many errors. Any help on where i have gone wrong will be greatly appreciated.

```
  #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


static Mat norm_0_255(InputArray _src) {
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    // Create and return normalized image:
    Mat dst;
    switch(src.channels()) {
        case 1:
            cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
            break;
        case 3:
            cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC3);
            break;
        default:
            src.copyTo(dst);
            break;
    }
    return dst;
}

static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);
        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
            images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}
//path to csv
string fn_csv = ("./at.csv");
//patch to haar cascade
string fn_haar = ("./haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
// These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
vector<Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;
read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);





    int im_width = images[0].cols;
    int im_height = images[0].rows;

Mat testSample = images[images.size() - 1];
int testLabel = labels[labels.size() - 1];

//cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer(10);

    //create the model

    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);

//load cascade

    CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
    haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);

    Mat Image
    for(;;) {
   Mat Image* img = cvLoadImage ("./Lena.png")

        Mat gray;
        cvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        // Find the face
        vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
        haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

        vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
        haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

        for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            // Process face
            Rect face_i = faces[i];
            // Crop the face from the image.
            Mat face = gray(face_i);

            Mat face_resized;
            cv::resize(face, face_resized, Size(im_width, im_height), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
            // prediction
            int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);

string text = format("Prediction = %d", prediction);
        }

    }

    int send () {
        std::string s= text;
        std::ofstream os("prediction.txt");
        if (!os) { std::cerr<<"Error writing to prediction"<<std::endl; } else {
            os << s;  
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: _"... but I'm receiving many errors..."_ Sou you'll need to become specific about these.

Comment: Always post errors if you get any no matter how many or how long. You can't expect anyone to figure out what's wrong without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code complete ? There are plenty of careless mistakes that could be easily corrected just by reading the error messages.

- no **main()** function
- missing semicolon lines 83 and 85
- same line 85:

  ```
  Mat Image* img = cvLoadImage ("./Lena.png");
  ```

  should be

  ```
  Image = imread("./Lena.png");
  ```

  **cvLoadImage()** is C (returning an `IplImage*`), not C++. (Although I don't understand why you are loading this same image over and over within an infinite loop.)
- `original` fron line 88 is not defined
- lines 90-94 are twice the same thing
- undefined `text` variable line 113 in **send()** function, probably the one line 107 you should pass as parameter.